# I want to display the related timelines

Tags: mysql, records

I want to display the related timelines and the criteria to display related timelines is :- can have commom tags, common events and same category id and the records must be display in the order most numbers of common events or tags timeline should come first.

My table structure looks like:-

```
timelines table :-
timeline_id, title, status, approved

tags:-
tag_id, tag_name

timeline_tags:-
timeline_id, tag_id

events:-
event_id, title

timeline_events:-
timeline_id, event_id
```

I got it working for only tags but how to use same logic with events too?

```
SELECT t.title
     , tt1.timeline_id
     , COUNT(tt1.tag_id) common_tag_count 
  FROM hg_timelines t 
  JOIN hg_timeline_tags tt1 
    ON t.timeline_id = tt1.timeline_id 
  JOIN hg_timeline_tags tt2 
    ON tt1.tag_id = tt2.tag_id 
 WHERE tt2.timeline_id = 1 
   AND t.category_id = 4 
   AND t.status = 1 
   AND t.approved = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY tt1.timeline_id 
HAVING tt1.timeline_id != 1 
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(tt1.tag_id) DESC
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out finding a solution for this. :(